# IntelliJ/Tomcat: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am working on a Web Application in IntelliJ Ultimate Edition on Ubuntu. I am getting an error in which states: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

What I did originally was that I went to File > New Project > Selected JavaEE - Web Application. By default in web.xml, the file had minimal code and looked like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

I made some modifications to the file and added the following below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>Module8</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Upon doing so, I created an index.html file under the web folder and added the following code to test whether tomcat was functioning (very elementary html code)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Module 8</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome to My login interface!</h3><br/>
    Please <a href = "login.html">Click Here to Login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Each time I deploy my project on the server and attempt to run it from within IntelliJ, I get a 404 error message and the reason given is as follows:

**The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.**

I used this video as a reference to setup Tomcat within IntelliJ:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Zp5suN1b1E&

I am stuck and out of options now. The entire weekend, I was trying to get Tomcat to function to no avail and I feel as if I have made zero progress spending hours daily trying to get Tomcat to function properly without writing any actual code. It's a bit frustrating to say the least.

Comment: In the Run/Debug configuration you can specify the URL to open as well as the context under which the app will be available (under the Deployment tab). Make sure both are specified correctly. In case the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello, that did not solve the problem. I will update the original answer with further details.

Comment: Original Post has been edited.

Comment: Refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html. Try the vanilla Tomcat installation. Share the project directory zipped if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you also get 404 if you select **index.html** in the Project panel, right-click and select **Run 'index.html'** from the menu?

Comment: skomisa, I don't get a 404 error, I get an error stating that index.html is already running on port 1099 but when I assess that, here is what I see: Alg3bra ~ $ netstat -lntp | grep 1099
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::1099                 :::*                    LISTEN      3433/java

Comment: To add onto that, that same process ID (3433) is utilizing a lot of ports concurrently per netstat -lntp

Comment: @Al-geBra And what is that process with ID 3433? Also, do you have another App Server configured such as Glassfish or Payara that you could try using instead of Tomcat? Also, what version of Tomcat are you using (not that it should matter)?

Comment: @skomisa the Process ID with 3433 is Java. Sadly, I don't have another App server configured, just tomcat. The version is 9.0.8.

Comment: OK. Port 1099 is in use because Tomcat is still running. Stop Tomcat (or kill PID 3433), then try **'Run index.html'** as mentioned in an earlier comment to see if that works.

Comment: I'm heck of confused right now despite having a degree in Computer Science lol. I killed all Java related Processes, then decided to run index.html instead of Tomcat and it opened up in my browser on the default Tomcat Port (8080) so yes, index.html is coming up.